# Swift 3 - How to manage a Json response

Tags: json, swift3

I have a Json with a segment of data of the vehicles i have.
This is an example of it:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "brand": "chevrolet",
      "model": "aveo",
      "version": "2012"
    },
    {
      "brand": "Toyota",
      "model": "Avalon",
      "version": "2010"
    }
  ],
  "benchmark": {
    "tiempo": "~0.1453 ms",
    "memoria": "2.1 MB"
  }
}
```

When i get the response, it is manipulated with the following code:

```
var json: [String:Any] = [:]
let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            do {
                let datos = responseString?.data(using: .utf8)
                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: datos!, options: []) as! [String:Any]    
                status = json["estado"] as! Int
        } catch {
            print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
        }
```

My problem is: When i try to manipulate the "data", i have no clue how to do that, just know json["data"] is an Any object.

I really appreciate any answer with it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would start here: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: or here: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: First thing, you have `data`, you are converting them to a string and then back to data. *Never* convert JSON data to a string. `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution but worked for me:

```
            let data = json["data"] as! [Any]
            for datos in data {
                var literal = datos as! [String:String]
                print(literal["version"]!)
                print(literal["model"]!)
            }
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SwiftyJSON is pretty easy to use and its one of the best swift library to handle json. Check it out here: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

A little example with your code:

```
var carsData = []
var status: Int

let json = JSON(data: data)

guard json != nil  else {
     print("JSON is nil")
     return
}

status = json["status"].int

//print the first car model
print(json["data"][0]["model"].string)
```

This is a untested example, check the SwiftyJSON GitHub Readme.

Comment: For now i can't use libraries, but i'll use it in my own projects. thanks a lot